# Vector to matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a vector v = [1 2 3 4 5 6 ] and I want to convert it to the matrix [1 2 ; 3 4 ; 5 6] meaning that each two adjacent indices become a row. But when I use

A = reshape(v, [], 2) I get A = [1 4 ; 2 5 ; 3 6]

Is there a MATLAB function that does that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reshape` to create the transposed matrix, then transpose it to get what you want:

```
reshape(v,2,[]).'
```

Comment: I'd do it this way too. As an additional note, the [`vec2mat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html) function from the Communications Toolbox could also be used: `A = vec2mat(V, 2)`